# Keep getting this error trying to build flutter app in android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Launching lib/main.dart on POT LX1 in debug mode...
../../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-3.2.4/lib/src/flutter_typeahead.dart:754:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.

- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
  ^
  ../../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-3.2.4/lib/src/flutter_typeahead.dart:767:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
  ^
  ../../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-3.2.4/lib/src/flutter_typeahead.dart:801:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((duration) {
  ^
  ../../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-3.2.4/lib/src/flutter_typeahead.dart:936:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'maxLengthEnforced'.
  maxLengthEnforced: widget.textFieldConfiguration.maxLengthEnforced,
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../../../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_field.dart:276:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const TextField({
  ^^^^^^^^^
  ../../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-3.2.4/lib/src/cupertino_flutter_typeahead.dart:558:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
  ^
  ../../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-3.2.4/lib/src/cupertino_flutter_typeahead.dart:571:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
  ^
  ../../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-3.2.4/lib/src/cupertino_flutter_typeahead.dart:605:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((duration) {
  ^
  ../../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-3.2.4/lib/src/cupertino_flutter_typeahead.dart:746:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'maxLengthEnforced'.
  maxLengthEnforced: widget.textFieldConfiguration.maxLengthEnforced,
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../../../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/text_field.dart:209:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const CupertinoTextField({
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/home/sheddy/snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1156
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command '/home/sheddy/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 15s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             76.7s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Can you provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and check the place you are using `!` without checking null. Also try with upgrading the package.

Comment: Thanks! Its building now after downgrading to flutter 2.10.0

Comment: If you were using v3. you needed to update the packages inside pubspec.yaml.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.